# I want to record a keyboard typing as though a human is typing

Tags: keyboard, vim, macros, screen-recorder

I am recording screencasts on OSX and Linux, and I am trying to set up some way to speed up recording of typing long blocks of code.

I need a way to take scripts or macros that I generate, and have it type during the recording, for smooth perfect typing. I also need to be able to control the speed - so sometimes typing is quick and sometimes it slows down (to help the viewer see what's going on).

I was thinking of generating vim macros, but they execute very fast and I can't figure out how to control the speed. Another option is keyboard macros (keyboard maestro, etc), but I can't find one that I can easily write scripts/macros for (they all seem to be GUI-focused).

OR: Is there a way for me to easily do this in post-production (video editing)? My current solution is to actually **edit out** the mistakes and typeovers. It produces a very nice video, but takes *hours* to edit a few minutes of typing.

Comment: Have you ever played with AutoIT? It have the ability to type keyboard strokes, set sleep time between each, etc.

Comment: That looks like it could work, but I should have mentioned I'm only on OSX and Linux.

Answer (score 2):

As you have mentioned that you need Linux and OsX supported software/packages, here are some:

1. [Python's automac package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/atomac): Automated Testing on Mac - test GUI applications
2. [Appium for mac](https://github.com/appium/appium-for-mac): 
   Proof of concept for automating a mac app with JSON wire protocol
3. [Sikuli Script](http://www.sikuli.org/): (Cross Platform)   automates anything you see on the screen. It uses image recognition to identify and control GUI components. It is useful when there is no easy access to a GUI's internal or source code
4. [Autopy](https://github.com/msanders/autopy): A simple, cross-platform GUI automation toolkit for Python

In case, you want one for Windows, then [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) should be your choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the shell I would suggest [playitagainsam](https://github.com/rfk/playitagainsam) - it supports 'fake typing' - meaning you press any key and it will be replaced by the correct one.

For simplicity [script and scriptreplay](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scriptreplay.1.html) might also be options.